# LocalStorage Reliability with Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile, cordova

I'm making a PhoneGap app that needs to store some user data. On the initial app startup, the user will be asked to type in a URL. Because the URL may potentially be long, I wish to save it on the user's device so the he doesn't need to re-enter the entire string every time he starts up the app.

Initially, I was planning on using LocalStorage for this. However, I've heard that LocalStorage doesn't save data very permanently. It would greatly hurt my app's usability if the user had to type in the URL more than once every month or so.

Should I use SQLite instead of LocalStorage for this purpose, or is LocalStorage reliable enough on most mobile devices for this kind of usage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should'nt use LocalStorage because it's no longer a persistant storage on IOS since 5.1 and also because Apple can reject your application.

You have several choices :

- Using the [File API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#File)
- Using [WebSQL](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage) (5 Mo max i think)
- Installing the [SQLite Plugin](https://github.com/lite4cordova/Cordova-SQLitePlugin)

For the last choice, you can also install [Lawnchair](https://github.com/lite4cordova/Cordova-SQLitePlugin#lawnchair-adapter-usage) (included) which provides an easy to use key value system on top of SQLite. You won't need to write any line of SQL to use SQLite.

Comment: Is the LocalStorage a problem on Phonegap 3.0 as well?

Comment: It is not a Phonegap problem but a Apple one. http://techblog.troyweb.com/index.php/2012/05/relocating-localstorage-in-ios-5-1-for-phonegap-applications/

Comment: If I don't want to install the SQLite plugin, can I just use Lawnchair with webkit-sqlite.js as the adapter?

Comment: Actually, webkit-sqlite.js is the adapter used by the SQLite Plugin, and it requires it. Installing and using the SQLite plugin + Lawnchair is a breeze don't worry. it just makes the development longer because you need to use the ios/android simulator to make it work and not just Rippler or AppGyver. If you don't like this solution, you can still use the File API btw

Comment: My bad! You can use Lawnchair + webkit-sqlite.js without the SQLite Plugin. Sorry for the mistake

Comment: OK, thank you! Right now, I'm using PhoneGap Build for compiling my app, so I'd prefer not to install any plugins.

Comment: You can still use plugins with PG Build, there is a list of supported plugins here https://build.phonegap.com/plugins. You just need to activate the ones you want in your config.xml :)